# Making "View" fill upp entire screen in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on a React-native project and stumbled upon issues when setting `width` and `height` using percentage values to a `View`. I have tried to set `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` but this does not work.

```
function CalendarPage() {
  return (
  <MainWrapper>
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
       <ScrollView>
        <StyleContentWrapper>
          <Paragraph> Hello World! </Paragraph>
        </StyleContentWrapper>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  </MainWrapper>
  );
}
```

```
const MainWrapper = styled.View`
  flex: 1; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
  background-color: lightgray; 
  color: white;
`
const StyleContentWrapper = styled.View`
  height: 100%;     // this does not work
  width: 100%;      // this does not work
  background-color: red;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-horizontal: 20px;

`
```

A quick explaination for the components:
`MainWrapper` covers the entire screen and is the base layer. The reason why it nests `SafeAreaView` is because this allows me to set a background color on the "safe area".

I have also nested another view called `StyleContentWrapper`inside a `ScrollView`, because I want everything inside to be scrollable.

[This is the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUbNI.png)

`StyledContentWrapper` or *The red box* does not cover the entire screen, despite having the styles of `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`. Why is this? Setting fixed width and height does work, but this is not the approach I want, because different devices has different widths and heights, and I want it to work for multiple screens with different widths and heights, hence the use of perecentage.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you try to pass `{flex: 1} to` `contentContainerStyle` in `<ScrollView />` ?

Comment: It gives about the same result, except the `height` of the red box is smaller. However, if I remove `ScrollView` and `SafeAreaView`,  the assigned width and height will work, might they be the cause?